# Capitalizing strings in C# containing html escape characters

Tags: c#, string, capitalization, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to title case some text that may contain html escape characters.  Is there any way of doing this other than with regular expressions?  Here's some example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


            string input = "B&amp;G fried pie";
            string output = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input.ToLowerInvariant());

            Console.WriteLine(output);  //Should be B&amp;G Fried Pie
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Another way I can think of is to replace `&amp`; with `&`, do my title case, then replace the `&` with `&amp`.

Comment: HtmlDecode ("html unescape", so to speak) the string, capitalize it, HtmlEncode it back...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Web.HttpUtility` class to decode and encode html strings, so your code would then look something like:

```
private static string ToTitleCase(string input)
{
    return input == null
        ? null
        : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo
            .ToTitleCase(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input.ToLowerInvariant())));
}
```

And in use it would look something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToTitleCase("B&amp;G fried pie"));
```